# WPF: Close the first window and open PDF in second window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two windows, in the first one(first.xaml), I allow the user to enter the name of the folder that they want pdf's to be taken and viewed. Once the user enters the folder name, I have a filewatchersystem to monitor that directory if pdf files are created. If a pdf file is created, I want it to open in the second window (pdfviewer.xaml) but I keep getting errors. Please, can you guide me? Not sure if  I am doing it correctly

```
void btfolder_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //close first window
    this.Hide()
    //Folder watch function
    filewatch();
}
//Once a file is created in the folder below function kicks off

void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Want the pdf file to open in PDFViewer.xaml
    PDFviewer pdfwindow = new PDFviewer();
    //I have a web browser(wbpdf) control to display the pdf 
    Web Browser wb = new WebBrowser();
    pdfwindow.wbpdf.Navigate(new Uri(file.pdf))
}
```

Comment: What error are  you getting?

Comment: Thank You Sham, for responding to my query. I have attached the error I am getting to the question

Comment: system.InvalidOperationException error when I initalize a web browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Dispatcher` to create the new window on the UI thread:

```
void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        PDFviewer pdfwindow = new PDFviewer();
        pdfwindow.wbpdf.Navigate(new Uri(file.pdf))
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank You, it worked perfectly.